# How to stretch sections in equal proportions?

Tags: javascript, html, css

### Problem

I want to stretch while fixing the ratio of `section`.
like this:

[image: like this]

I applied `max-width: 100%;` & `height: auto;` to `<section>` but didn't work.

**Finally, I want to do this:**

[image: this]

By the way, I use CSS grid.
How do I make `section` stretch at the same rate?

### Code

```css
html { font-size: 62.5%; }
body { display: block; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; outline: 0; font-size: 100%; font: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; background: transparent; box-sizing: border-box; }  /* reset */
#items {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 3.8rem 4.6rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(240px, 1fr));
}
.item {
  text-align: center;
  width: 25.35rem;
}
.item img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.item h2 {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  margin-top: 1.6rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}
.item p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin-bottom: .8rem;
}
.item h2, .item p, .item span {
  text-align: left;
}
.item span {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  border: .1rem solid black;
  border-radius: .3rem;
  margin-right: .6rem;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  padding: .3rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="items">
    <section class="item">
      <img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190312/20190312210318.png">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Easy explanation</p>
      <span>tag</span>
      <span>tags</span>
      <span>of</span>
      <span>various</span>
      <span>lengths</span>
      <span>tag</span>
      <span>tag</span>
      <span>tag</span>
    </section>
    <section class="item">
      <img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190312/20190312210315.png" alt="b" />
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Easy explanation</p>
    </section>
    <section class="item">
      <img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190312/20190312210313.png" alt="c" />
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Easy explanation</p>
    </section>
    <section class="item">
      <img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190312/20190312210310.png" alt="d" />
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Easy explanation</p>
    </section>
    <section class="item">
      <img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190312/20190312210308.png" alt="e" />
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Easy explanation</p>
    </section>
    <section class="item">
      <img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190312/20190312210354.png" alt="f" />
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Easy explanation</p>
    </section>
    <section class="item">
      <img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190312/20190312210352.png" alt="g" />
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Easy explanation</p>
    </section>
    <section class="item">
      <img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190312/20190312210349.png" alt="h" />
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Easy explanation</p>
    </section>
  </div>
```

Comment: css `flex` property?

Comment: @brk I tried with flexbox, but as with the current CSS grid, `section` did not scale.. Why is that? :/

Comment: @sweaver2112 Surely it is.  I'm sorry. I thought it's easy to understand..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying `max-width` was the cause of everything.
Just by changing two places, it works as expected.

```css
html { font-size: 62.5%; }
body { display: block; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; outline: 0; font-size: 100%; font: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; background: transparent; box-sizing: border-box; }  /* reset */
#items {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 3.8rem 4.6rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(240px, 1fr));
}
.item {
  text-align: center;
  /* width: 25.35rem; */    /* ① delete */
}
.item img {
  width: 100%;    /* ② max-width -> width */
  height: auto;
}
.item h2 {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  margin-top: 1.6rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}
.item p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin-bottom: .8rem;
}
.item h2, .item p, .item span {
  text-align: left;
}
.item span {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  border: .1rem solid black;
  border-radius: .3rem;
  margin-right: .6rem;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  padding: .3rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="items">
    <section class="item">
      <img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190312/20190312210318.png">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Easy explanation</p>
      <span>tag</span>
      <span>tags</span>
      <span>of</span>
      <span>various</span>
      <span>lengths</span>
      <span>tag</span>
      <span>tag</span>
      <span>tag</span>
    </section>
    <section class="item">
      <img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190312/20190312210315.png" alt="b" />
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Easy explanation</p>
    </section>
    <section class="item">
      <img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190312/20190312210313.png" alt="c" />
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Easy explanation</p>
    </section>
    <section class="item">
      <img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190312/20190312210310.png" alt="d" />
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Easy explanation</p>
    </section>
    <section class="item">
      <img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190312/20190312210308.png" alt="e" />
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Easy explanation</p>
    </section>
    <section class="item">
      <img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190312/20190312210354.png" alt="f" />
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Easy explanation</p>
    </section>
    <section class="item">
      <img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190312/20190312210352.png" alt="g" />
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Easy explanation</p>
    </section>
    <section class="item">
      <img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190312/20190312210349.png" alt="h" />
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Easy explanation</p>
    </section>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about the following. You can use `@media queries` to make a responsive grid.

```css
html { font-size: 62.5%; }
body { display: block; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; outline: 0; font-size: 100%; font: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; background: transparent; box-sizing: border-box; }  /* reset */
#items {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 3.8rem 4.6rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  padding: 3.8rem;
}
.item {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red; /* Just for demonstration */
}
.item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.item h2 {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  margin-top: 1.6rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}
.item p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin-bottom: .8rem;
}
.item h2, .item p, .item span {
  text-align: left;
}
.item span {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  border: .1rem solid black;
  border-radius: .3rem;
  margin-right: .6rem;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  padding: .3rem;
}


.item {
  grid-column: span 12;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .item {
    grid-column: span 6;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
  .item {
    grid-column: span 4;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="items">
    <section class="item">
      <img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190312/20190312210318.png">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Easy explanation</p>
      <span>tag</span>
      <span>tags</span>
      <span>of</span>
      <span>various</span>
      <span>lengths</span>
      <span>tag</span>
      <span>tag</span>
      <span>tag</span>
    </section>
    <section class="item">
      <img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190312/20190312210315.png" alt="b" />
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Easy explanation</p>
    </section>
    <section class="item">
      <img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190312/20190312210313.png" alt="c" />
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Easy explanation</p>
    </section>
    <section class="item">
      <img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190312/20190312210310.png" alt="d" />
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Easy explanation</p>
    </section>
    <section class="item">
      <img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190312/20190312210308.png" alt="e" />
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Easy explanation</p>
    </section>
    <section class="item">
      <img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190312/20190312210354.png" alt="f" />
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Easy explanation</p>
    </section>
    <section class="item">
      <img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190312/20190312210352.png" alt="g" />
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Easy explanation</p>
    </section>
    <section class="item">
      <img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190312/20190312210349.png" alt="h" />
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Easy explanation</p>
    </section>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you!
I tried copy & paste in exactly the same way, but in my environment it did not stretch like a code snippet.. :'(  Height didn't change..

Comment: @POP do you have a viewport specified in your header eg: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">`?

Comment: Yes. I tried to set the same viewport as the example, but still `height` doesn't change. Hmmm.. I watched carefully and there was no mistake, but why..

Comment: Is the height overridden by some other CSS or JS?

Comment: Ah! I overlooked the `max-width` of `.item img` being changed to `width` !  And it seems that this was all the cause of non-stretching. Just delete the `.item { width: 25.35 rem; }` of the question code and change the `.item img { max-width: 100%; }` to `width: 100%`.  ->  I confirmed that it works as expected without `@media queries` !
Thank you very much!

Comment: @POP if that is the real solution you can add that as an answer and help others with it

Comment: Oh, I can also answer own questions!